# Server program gets stuck at accept function

Tags: c, multithreading, server

I am working on a server application in C using Pthreads(Linux).Everything works fine,  clients can connect with the server and transfer data. The problem being faced is that my software keeps stuck at accept till it does not receive a new request from a client.

Here is my code:

```
while((connfd = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr (socklen_t*)&clntSock)))
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");


        if( pthread_create( &thr, NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &connfd) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        puts("Handler assigned");
    }
```

I am able to run multiple threads but my main thread gets stuck at the `accept` function. How can I solve this problem so that I can do other work in the main thread while my other threads are running?

Comment: are you setting your socket to nonblocking?

Comment: Isn't that because of `while` for blocking sockets?

Comment: @Alejandro How can i set the socket to non blocking?

Comment: @Simer `fcntl(sock_desc, F_SETFL, fcntl(sock_desc, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);`  Try that and let us know the behavior

Comment: Can't you do the accept call in another thread?

Comment: ' (void*) &connfd)'  NO.  Stop doing that.

Comment: Why do you want to unblock it anyway?  You are creating a server<>client handling thread for each new client, (mostly, see 'NO' above).

Comment: Setting the socket to non-blocking will result in most calls to Accept() to return -1 and so generate a while(true) loop, continaully creating new threads and passing the address of -1 as the aux parameter.  How is that helpful at all?

Comment: @MartinJames I want to unblock because i want to do some other work in the main thread. After making it non-Blocking i have modified the routine to create a thread only if accept returns > 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, `accept` is a blocking call unless you specify the socket to be nonblocking.

You can achieve this with the following:

```
fcntl(sock_desc, F_SETFL, fcntl(sock_desc, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);`
```

You can do error checking with the return value from `fcntl`

Comment: Make sure that `connfd` is also  valid in the case where `accept` doesn't block when there's no actual connection to accept

Comment: i have posted a new question plz have a look at that.here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756210/recv-failed-bad-file-descriptor

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve what you want.

1. You can set the socket to nonblocking. In that case `accept` will return immediately.
2. You can use `select` (or `poll`) to wait until the socket is ready to accept or a timeout occurs. If you put that into your main loop you can check after `select` if it returned because an incoming connection is waiting (and `accept` it) or if the timeout occurred (and you do your other stuff).